# Parse CSV column contains mixed values as string and JSON using python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

I have a CSV column called ref_type as shown in the below screen shot with mixed types which are sometimes string and other rows as JSON. I am reading this CSV using pandas read_csv method which inherits the type as object

[image: sample_data]

i would like to convert the JSON part as below

[image]

Please help to parse above scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show your data as copyable **text** instead of images? We cannot copy from images, hence cannot test anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just build a dataframe containing the new columns *by hand* and join it to the first one. Unfortunately you have not provided copyable data so I just used mine.

Original df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ref': ['Outcomes', 'API-TEST', '{"from":"abc", "to": "def"}',
                   'Manual(add)', '{"from": "gh", "to": "ij"}', 'Migration']})
```

Giving:

```
                           ref
0                     Outcomes
1                     API-TEST
2  {"from":"abc", "to": "def"}
3                  Manual(add)
4   {"from": "gh", "to": "ij"}
5                    Migration
```

Extract only json data from `ref` column:

```
data = []           # future data of the dataframe
ix = []             # future index
cols = set()        # future columns
for name, s in df[['ref']].iterrows():
    try:
        d = json.loads(s['ref'])
        ix.append(name)                   # if we could decode feed the future dataframe
        cols.update(set(d.keys()))
        data.append(d)
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        pass                              # else ignore the line

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(data, ix, cols), how='left')
```

gives:

```
                           ref   to from
0                     Outcomes  NaN  NaN
1                     API-TEST  NaN  NaN
2  {"from":"abc", "to": "def"}  def  abc
3                  Manual(add)  NaN  NaN
4   {"from": "gh", "to": "ij"}   ij   gh
5                    Migration  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution and its not the best but its working.

I already have a flatten JSON function as below

```
def flatten_json_columns(df, json_cols, custom_df):
"""
This function flattens JSON columns to individual columns
It merges the flattened dataframe with expected dataframe to capture missing columns from JSON
:param df: CSV raw dataframe
:param json_cols: custom data columns in CSV's
:param custom_df: expected dataframe
:return: returns df pandas dataframe
"""

# Loop through all JSON columns
for column in json_cols:
    if not df[column].isnull().all():
        # Replace None and NaN with empty braces
        df[column].fillna(value='{}', inplace=True)            
        # Deserialize's a str instance containing a JSON document to a Python object
        df[column] = df[column].apply(json.loads)            
        # Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table
        column_as_df = pd.json_normalize(df[column])
        # Extract main column name and attach it to each sub column name
        column_as_df.columns = [f"{column}_{subcolumn}" for subcolumn in column_as_df.columns]
        # Merge extracted result from custom_data field with expected fields
        result_df = pd.merge(column_as_df, custom_df, how='left')
        # Drop the temp column and merge the flattened dataframe with orginal dataframe
        df = df.merge(result_df, right_index=True, left_index=True)
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, custom_df], axis=1)

# Return dataframe with flatten columns
return df
```

my data frame looks like below

[image: ref_type_data_as_string_and_json]

I created a another column called ref_type_json from ref_type by putting only json rows and ignoring all strings. instead of strings i returned none

```
ref_type_df['ref_type_json'] = [column if column[0] == '{' else None for column in ref_type_df['ref_type']]
```

now the ref_type_df looks as below

[image]

i also created empty expected data frame so that the output of flatten JSON function aligns with the out put of expected dataframe

```
ref_type_expected = {
    'ref_type_json_fromNumber': [],
    'ref_type_json_toNumber': [],
    'ref_type_json_comment': []
}

ref_type_expected_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ref_type_expected)
```

Finally, I invoked the flatten JSON function which converts the JSON to columns

```
result_df = flatten_json_columns(df=ref_type_df,
                             json_cols=['ref_type_json'],
                             custom_df=ref_type_expected_df)

result_df.drop('ref_type_json', axis=1)
```

my result data frame looks as below

[image]

Please let me know if you have a better solution for it.